# Make it clear the OP has the "final vote" on suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, design

Now that all sites requires at least two votes to approve or reject a suggested edit, there is  chance to get into confusing situations like: (for simplicity using case of only 2, like here on Meta)

1. Single vote from ordinary user was needed to approve/reject the suggested edit. ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9311))
2. One user has voted to approve/reject the suggested then afterwards other (ordinary) user cast opposite vote and it went through without needing a third vote. ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9343))

The second is more confusing in my opinion; when I saw that page I thought "well, this is a bug, let's report it!" and in the last moment noticed the one rejecting was actually the author of the post.

Same way like moderators are marked with a diamond and thus it's easy to understand why they have the final vote, please mark the post authors as well. Background color would be suitable, same color as appears in the question.

Rough mock up:

> [image]

Comment: It makes sense. It is already done for the questions, and it could be done for suggested edits. In both the cases, I could see if the user is the author of the question/post by scrolling the page, but for questions I can do it without scrolling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done. When the a user approves or rejects a suggested edit to his *own* post, his display name is given a special background color (the same style as when he comments on his post).

Examples from the question:

- [Example 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9311)
- [Example 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9343)