# Suggested edit approved with one approval vote

Tags: support, edits, review, suggested-edits

I have rejected [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2564582) today which was approved with only one approval vote.

The edit received only three votes with two rejects and one approval.

The editor already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2564567) the same edit before which got rejected with three reject votes.

One more thing is, the approved reviewer(Jack Ramzi) name's label has a blue background unlike others.

Comment: He seems to be the owner of the post.

Comment: For reference, the [Suggested Edits FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/225020) says, "The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Suggested edits review OP's vote is binding vote. In other words OP's review is the final review same as moderators. Here OP is the OP of *the post* it can be either question or answer. Here *Jack Ramzi* is the OP of that post.

Comment: so, the Op name's label will be with blue background in the review page, is it?

Comment: @Azik - Yes it is.

Comment: @Azik for what it's worth, the blue background was added only after I [asked for such a feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152419/152859) to prevent exactly such confusion.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Good to know that. Thanks for that request.

Answer (score 1):

Jack Ramzi is the original author of the question, and therefore the owner of the post. A post's owner's decision to accept or reject an edit is final.