# How can a user with less than 10 rep can do a review on suggested edits?

Tags: support, reputation, review, suggested-edits

I am a member of the [Magento Stack Exchange site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/about) (in beta) and I have a 770 reputation points.

Recently, I was reviewing Close votes posts and found that a user with just [seven reputation points participated in a review](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2975) of suggested edits.

But the review page says I need a minimum of 1000 reputation points to review a suggested edit.

[image]

**How could that user do that?**

**Is this a bug?**

Comment: Probably he reviewed an edit suggested on his own post.

Comment: is it possible, because I don't remember i was allowed to review edit's made on my posts when I had fewer rep points.

Comment: Don't like the look of those auto-shapes in red. Boooo.

Comment: so, which color you would like to see? I mean which color could attract attention?

Comment: @Shathish free hand red circles are ideal. You can also draw free hand arrows. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: all right! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any user can review suggested edit on his own posts without having enough privilege. That user [review an edit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2975) on his own post. If any edit is suggested on your post, you will be notified to review it.

Also, if the OP of the post review an edit, the background color of his name will look like this:

> [image]

(Suggested by [@Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152419/187824))

Comment: hmmm may be I have a bad memory then ;)

Comment: No +1 until you put FHRC! Worth also to mention, the background of the user was changed [per my request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152419/152859) for this reason exactly, lol... :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah I needed to mention it. Updated :-)

Comment: now there was an edit to my question and I got no notification to review it. why (out of curiosity)?

Comment: @Shathish - Which question are you talking about? And how did you know that there is an edit on your question?

Comment: @Shathish user with full edit privilege doesn't need his edit to be approved. In your case, diamond dev has made the edit on your question here. Is was also a trivial edit (less than 6 characters) so in case of non trivial edit you will get notification in your inbox, linking to the revisions page. :)

Comment: @hims056: I mentioned about this same question, edited by m0sa. There was an update message "an edit has been made to your post" over my question. Sha Wiz Dow Ard cleared my doubt! :)